# Uploading images to imgur

Tags: imgur

I'm currently busy with creating a site where I can put content etc.

When I want to add an image I can upload it from desktop or with a url. I know there are some api's to use, but I've contacted IMGUR but they still didn't reply. I want to know; When I upload via my own website directly to IMGUR with an api, is there a limit?

Because I want all uploads anonymously, so no images saved into my account.

Comment: This information should be available at imgur. Read the API description.

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at the IMGUR API. https://api.imgur.com/

The Imgur API uses a credit allocation system to ensure fair distribution of capacity. Each application can allow approximately 1,250 uploads per day or approximately 12,500 requests per day. If the daily limit is hit five times in a month, then the app will be blocked for the rest of the month. The remaining credit limit will be shown with each requests response in the X-RateLimit-ClientRemaining HTTP header.

If you find you're being rate limited, and your app is completely free (and without ads), then you can submit a request to be white-listed. We ask that you simply fill out this form and we'll let you know if you qualify.

We also limit each user (via their IP Address) for each application, this is to ensure that no single user is able to spam an application. This limit will simply stop the user from requesting more data for an hour. We recommend that each application takes precautions against spamming by implementing rate limiting on their own applications. Each response will also include the remaining credits for each user in the X-RateLimit-UserLimit HTTP header.

Each request contains rate limit information in the HTTP response headers.

You can also check the current rate limit status on your application by sending a GET request to https://api.imgur.com/3/credits